# Using Javas System.out.format to align integer values

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am trying to produce right aligned numbers looking a bit like this:

```
  12345
   2345
```

but I clearly does not understand the syntax. I have been trying to follow [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). and Come up with the following attempt (it is integers so d and I want width 7 and 0 decimals):

```
public class test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.format("%7.0d%n", 12345);
        System.out.format("%7.0d%n",  2345);
    }
}
```

but no matter what I do I seem to end up with `IllegalFormatPrecisionException`. Is there a way to do this using this tool? If not how else would you do it?

Comment: The `.0` is for floating point.  You don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.format("%7d%n", 12345);
        System.out.format("%7d%n",  2345);
    }
}
```

Essentially this code asks Java to pad the string with spaces so that the output is exactly 7 characters.

Comment: +1: You don't need the space. I would use `%n` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public class test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.format("%7d%n", 12345);
        System.out.format("%7d%n",  2345);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the linked page, it shows this:

`System.out.format("%,8d%n", n);                //  -->  " 461,012"`

You can omit the comma, and change the 8 to a 7

Answer (score 0):

converter %d is for integers and %f is for float. "%7.0d%n" is used with a float(i.e., as %7.0f%n) and "%7d%n" is used for integer representation.this is the reason for IllegalFormatPrecisionException exception.

Reference link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html