# Right align integers (Java)

Tags: java, formatting

I wanted to format a table as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvwgy.png). But I have problem right-aligning integers. As can be seen in picture, the first four rows at the top, integers are right aligned. Is there any way to align integers via `System.out.printf()` or `String.format()` as such? What I tried to do so far resembles it; but its not the same. Integers are left aligned.

```
        String line = String.format("\n\nREGISTERS:\n");
    line += String.format("%-21s %+05d\n%-21s %02d\n%-21s %+05d\n%-21s %02d\n%-21s %02d\n\n","accumulator",accum,
            "instructionCounter",instructionCounter,"instructionRegister",instructionRegister,"operationCode",operationCode,"operand",operand);
    line += (String.format("MEMORY:\n"));
    line += (String.format("%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d\n",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));



    for(int i = 0; i < memory.length; i += 10){
        line += String.format("%2d ", i);
        for(int j = i; j < i+9; j++){
            line += String.format("%+05d ", memory[j]);
        }
        line += "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javas System.out.format to align integer values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215282/using-javas-system-out-format-to-align-integer-values)

Comment: @shmosel I tried all the solutions provided in that question before posting, none of them worked. I tried them again after you posted. Especially the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way may be to format the integers as a string by passing a `String.format()` to itself like this:
`String.format("'%5s'", String.format("%02d", instructionCounter))`
So that line in your code becomes something like this:

```
line += String.format("%-21s%+05d\n%-21s%6s%-21s%+05d\n%-21s%6s%-21s%6s",
                              "accumulator",accum,
                              "instructionCounter",String.format("%02d\n", instructionCounter),
                              "instructionRegister",instructionRegister,
                              "operationCode",String.format("%02d\n", operationCode),
                              "operand",String.format("%02d\n", operand) );
```

Producing output as:

```
REGISTERS:
accumulator          +0000
instructionCounter      00
instructionRegister  +0000
operationCode           00
operand                 00
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It will make it cleaner and concise, but doesn't solve the problem. thanks.

Comment: This output formats the table as you've shown. If this outputs the integers as right-aligned, but doesn't solve the problem, then what is the original problem?

Comment: my bad, it does. I was doing something else and messed up.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to see if there was more to your problem or if I misunderstood, cheers